# How to convert html date picker to razor syntax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a this model in my project:

```
public class dashboardModel{
        public string dateTime {get;set;}
        public string name {get;set;}
}
```

and use that in my project:

```
@model projectManagement.Models.dashboardModel
```

and convert this html code :

```
<textarea  class="mb-1 metro-input"></textarea>
```

to this razor syntax:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.todoExplain, new {@class="mb-1 metro-input"} )
```

and have this html date picker:

```
<date-picker :column="1" v-model="date" mode="single" />
```

I do not know how convert that html date picker to razor syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You Can Use this

```
<div class="editor-field">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Dateadd, new { @Value = DateTime.Now, id = "datepicker" })
      
      
    </div>
    $(document).ready(function () { $("#datepicker").datepicker({ });});
```